# Что такое "Ненужное присваивание значения name_variable" ? В чём ошибка?

Tags: c#

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace try_c_sharp
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string str = "3.14";
            float p;
            float.TryParse(str, out p); //предупреждение возникает здесь на переменной p

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Значение, присвоенное переменной `p` внутри `TryParse`, нигде не используется. Добавьте:

```
float.TryParse(str, out p);
Console.WriteLine(p);
```

Или (C# 7.0)

```
float.TryParse(str, out _);
```